# How To Find Id From Anchor Tag Using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

Here i am trying to find the taskid present in anchor tag using Jquery on click of that anchor tag having class=POtskComment.
But as i click the anchor tag taskid id is undefined.
Any help will be heartly thankful.Thank You
Below is my Html

```
 @foreach (var item1 in Model)
                    {
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <a class="POtskComment" taskid="@item1.TaskId" tskassinid="@item1.TskAssId" tskname="@item1.TaskName">
                                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item1.TaskName)
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    }
```

Below Is Jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function (event) {
    $(".POtskComment").click(function (event) {

        var paramTaskId3 = $(this).closest("tr").find("td").attr("tskid");

        var parameter = { taskId: paramTaskId };
        $.ajax({
            url: "/TaskAssignedDailyLogs/_POIndex",
            type: "get",
            dataType: "html",
            data: parameter,
            success: function (data)
            {
                $("#reportResult").html(data);
            }
        });

    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var paramTaskId3 = $(this).attr("taskid");
```

the attribute is also misspelled

Comment: Adding on to this, `"tskid"` should be `"taskid"`, looks like a typo in the original code.

Answer (score 0):

typo: it should be 'taskid' and not 'tskid'
your attr is on the anchor tag, and not td tag, 
hence use `$(this).attr('taskid');`